# Ignore update data if exist in mysql by node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, redis

I'm going to check id of my data if exist in mysql update it and if not create it, but in select result it dosen't work and go to esle section and create action most of the times and got Duplicate entry error. at the end I run this file by infinite loop.
I should tell this when I have a lot data in redis this problem will happen.

I'll be glad if help me, thanks :)

Here is my code :

```
var 
mysql = require('mysql'),
redis = require('redis'),
infiniteLoop = require('infinite-loop'),
client = redis.createClient(),
lop = new infiniteLoop,
config = require( __dirname + '/app/Config').config,

con = function() {

    return mysql.createConnection({
        host     : config.db_host,
        user     : config.db_user,
        password : config.db_pass,
        database : config.db_name
    });

},

insertDB = function( data ) {

    var connection = con();

    connection.connect( function( err ) {

        connection.query( 'SELECT * FROM real_user WHERE id =' + data.id, function( err, res ) {

            if ( err ) {

                data = JSON.stringify(data);

                client.lpush('aipi', data, function(err,reply) {
                    if ( err ) throw err;
                });

            }

            console.log( "out", data.id, res.length, res );

            if ( typeof res != 'undefined' && res.length > 0  ) {

                console.log( "update", data.id );

                connection.query( 'UPDATE real_user SET ? WHERE id =' + res[0].id, { request_count: data.request_count, updated_at: data.created_at }, 
                    function( err, res ) {
                    if ( err ) throw err;
                });

            } else {

                console.log( "create", data.id );

                connection.query( 'INSERT INTO real_user SET ?', data,  function( err, res ) {
                    if ( err ) throw err;
                });
            }
          connection.end();

        });

    });

},

run = function() {

    var data;

    client.brpop('aipi', 0, function(err, reply) {

        if ( reply[1] ) {

            data = JSON.parse(reply[1]);

            insertDB(data);
        }

    });

};

lop.add(run, []).run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by :

**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

```
connection.connect( function( err ) {

    connection.query( "INSERT INTO real_user SET ? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE updated_at = '" + data.created_at
     + "', request_count = '" + data.request_count + "'", 
        data,  function( err, res ) {
            connection.end();
        });

    });
```